# Efficient way to query similarly-named tables with identical column names

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm building a report in SSRS which takes data from several tables with similar names. There are three different 'sets' of tables - i.e., 123xxx, 456xxx, and 789xxx. Within these groups, the only difference in the table names is a three-digit code for a worksite, so, for example, we might have a table called 123001, 123010, and 123011. Within each set of tables, the columns have the same names.

The problem is that there are about 15 different sites, and I'm taking several columns from each site and each group of tables. Is there a more efficient way to write that query than to write out the name of every single column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is but I feel like the use of aliases on your tables would make it much easier to undestand/follow your query building.

Also, if you aren't comparing values on the tables at all, then maybe a union between each table select would help make sense too.

Comment: A union combines the results of alike queries So in your case:
`SELECT a,b,c FROM 123010
UNION
SELECT a,b,c FROM 123011
UNION 
Select a,b,c FROM 123001`

Answer (score 1):

I would give each table an alias.

```
SELECT s1t1.name 
FROM Site1Table1 as s1t1;
```

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing. It was tedious, but it worked.

Comment: It'll make more sense when you forget what you were doing now, later, and come back to it! Godspeed